# Creating hash map for employee class in java

Tags: java, oop, collections

I have been asked in the interview to create a `HashMap` for the Employee class :

```
class Emp { 
  int id;    
  int age;
  String name;  
}
```

How to create the `HashMap` of this class, which field should I keep as key and which should be value?

Comment: If id is unique then you can use id as a key and Emp object as a value

Comment: The immediate question you must ask him/her is what is the unique field here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the creation of map solely depends on the unique attribute of the object, which can be considered as key. Also the key should be of a type whose hashcode does not change(i.e. Immutable implementations) with every new object creation (as per the java documentation).

here in the code, ID field can be considered key and the employee object can be treated as the value. However based on the use case requirement the key can be different attribute as well.

Comment: hi, Thanks for answering vivek. I understood the funda. but  why there is -1 value beside my post?

Comment: I am not sure of that, Cause I have not down marked the question.

Comment: Also, if you like an answer you can mark it as answer and upvote it.

Comment: Yes Vivek. I got this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a little search about hashmaps in the internet to get familiar with the concepts. As for the answer, my suggestion would be to use the **id** field as your key. You can create it as below:

```
Map<Integer, Emp> employeeMap = new Hashmap<Integer, Emp>()
```

Then you can add an employee as

```
employeeMap.put(employee.id, employee)
```

Comment: My bad, you need to use Integer. Been developing C++ for too long now. :)